# Forms do not create new entry in database with Django

Tags: database, python-3.x, forms, django-2.0

I try to create a Form to create new players. Opening the url works well and when i clic on submit button, i get no error but redirected to the home project.
When i check in the admin part, i can not see the data i posted in the form before. Moreover, i can not see the picture i send before in the media directory.
The database is not updated when informations are posted with forms in Django 2.1

I don't know if i set right the POST request.

Maybe a bug or i miss something?

template.py

```
<h1>Add a new player</h1>

{% if saved %}

    <p>Player has been saved</p>

{% endif %}

<p>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action=".">
       {% csrf_token %}
       {{ form.as_p }}
       <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
</p>
```

view.py

```
from game.models import Scenario, Player
from .forms import ScenarioForm, NewPlayerForm
def newplayer(request):
    saved = False
    form = NewPlayerForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():
        player = Player()
        player.pseudo = form.cleaned_data['pseudo']
        player.gender = form.cleaned_data['gender']
        player.picture = form.cleaned_data['picture']
        player.save()
        saved = True

    return render(request, 'game/newplayer.html', {
        'form': form, 
        'saved': saved
    })
```

model.py

```
class Player(models.Model):
    pseudo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Homme'),
        ('F', 'Femme'),
        ('O','Other'),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "player"
        ordering = ['pseudo']

    def __str__(self):
        """ 
        Cette méthode que nous définirons dans tous les modèles
        nous permettra de reconnaître facilement les différents objets que 
        nous traiterons plus tard dans l'administration
        """
        return self.pseudo
```

Form.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Scenario, Player
class NewPlayerForm(forms.Form):

    pseudo = forms.CharField(required=True)
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Homme'),
        ('F', 'Femme'),
        ('O', 'Other'),
    )
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, required=True)
    picture = forms.ImageField()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would put a comment but I can't do that until I have 50 reputation, but...

In your view, at the `<form>` element, you have `action="."`, which means if you submit it, that will run through the function at the current url. Is your urlpattern for newplayer() pointing to that same page? Because you said you're being ***redirected*** to your home project, but your function doesn't have a return redirect(). And the return render() you have doesn't say it goes to something like index.html, which is the typical home directory as far as I'm used to.

**Mind putting your url patterns in here?**

Also, because your view has a `saved` variable, and because of your control flow, no matter what you do, you will always get the page returning with `<p>Player has been saved</p>` because your current setup makes it always exist. If you did something like the following, then it would show you the update on that page properly *(but I still need to see the url patterns):*

**views.py**

```
def newplayer(request):
    # You might have to change some of the parameters in the form object below.
    # Example: I know if you made your own validation instead of django's,
    # object.photo = request.FILES.get('uploadphoto', False) would get the picture fine,
    # but I'm not sure about django forms.
    form = NewPlayerForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        player = Player()
        player.pseudo = form.cleaned_data['pseudo']
        player.gender = form.cleaned_data['gender']
        player.picture = form.cleaned_data['picture']
        player.save()
        saved = 'Player has been saved!'
        return render(request, 'success.html', {'saved': saved})
    else:
        return render(request, 'create_player.html', {'form': form})
```

**template.html**

```
{% if saved %}
    <p>{{ saved }}</p>
{% else %)
   <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action=".">
       {% csrf_token %}
       {{ form.as_p }}
       <input type="submit" value="submit" />
   </form>
{% endif %}
```